# Editing and saving local HTML file using TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I'm trying to load a local HTML file in `TWebBrowser`, edit the content and save it.

I've read some suggestions from [this](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=46686) article and tried as follows:

**1) Loading the document:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('file:///C:\Tmp\input.html');
end;
```

**2) Putting the component in editable mode:**

In the `TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).designMode := 'on';
end;
```

At this point, the component is editable and I can modify its text.

**3) Saving the edited document:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream : TStringStream;
begin
  (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).designMode := 'no';

  Stream := TStringStream.Create((WebBrowser1.Document as IHtmlDocument2).body.innerHTML);
  try
    Stream.SaveToFile('C:\Tmp\output.html');
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

At the first line, an `EOleException` is raised:

[image: Picture displaying the EOleException message dialog in italian language, saying: 'Impossibile ottenere la proprietà designMode. Argomento non valido']

In english it should be something like:

> Cannot get designMode property. Invalid argument

Comment: Shouldn't it be _'off''_ instead of _'no'_ for `designMode`?

Comment: @BrakNicku: I thought it, but setting _'off'_ value causes an Access Violation to be raised

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752573(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: @BrakNicku: You're right! The only problem was the `'no'` instead of `'off'` (I don't understand what was going wrong on my project, but in a new example project it works good just changing `'no'` to `'off'`). Post it as an answer so I can accept it